# Android Auto development from outside service area

Tags: android, android-auto

I don't know if this is off topic for this site or not. So please accept my apologies if it is off topic.

I wan't to try Android Auto for development purposes. So firstly I am trying to start the Android Auto Desktop Head Unit emulator (DHU) and prepare my device following this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/testing/). But as I try to download the Android Auto app, Google Play will not allow me to download as it is not supported in my country. No problem, I downloaded the apk using Apk downloader site and installed that. When I open the app, it's not allowed to proceed as it detects my country isn't supported for this feature. To overcome this I tried the following steps:

1. Clear the app data of Android Auto app and force stop it.
2. Used tunnel bear vpn to fake my location to USA.
3. Fake my GPS using Fake GPS app to USA.
4. Now open the Android Auto app to continue.

But still it doesn't let me continue, the app says my country does not support this. So I am stuck here unable to begin development as I won't be able to test. Am I missing something? Is there any other way to bypass this?

Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

N.B.: I have developer options enabled in my Nexus 5 device(api level 23).

Comment: The Google Play Store uses the billing address for the primary payment method on the account that is logged into the device. Android Auto may be using this to confirm its eligibility. Try removing the account you have logged into the device, though you may need to clear the cache for Play Services, and / or reinstall Android Auto.

Comment: Current list of supported countries for Auto: https://www.android.com/auto/faq/

Comment: How to change Google Play country: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en

Comment: @salminnella thanks for your comment. I will try to follow your advice and let you know the results.....

Comment: Any luck on your testing?

Comment: @salminnella sorry for late response. I was gone for a short vacation. As I am busy now with official main project, I will provide you the test results as soon as I am done with that.....